# Cooling Tower Geodata in Colorado

Tags: openstreetmap, data

I would like to explore outbreaks of Legionnaires disease in relation to cooling tower locations. This work would be confined to Colorado, potentially even just the Denver metro area.

I am wondering if anyone has ideas on where I might find data on cooling tower locations for Colorado?

If no dataset currently exists, I am considering digitizing cooling tower locations from satellite imagery, but that would pose obvious challenges.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm interested in cooling towers on buildings, not large cooling towers associated with power plants.

Comment: Opendata Denver Buildings http://data.opencolorado.org/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-building-outlines

Comment: If you don't find what you are looking for a geodata, might I suggest you to try and post it in http://opendata.stackexchange.com/   ?